# Is there any way to check if iCloud backup is set up for iOS device?

Tags: ios, icloud

What I need is:

1. Know programmatically if the iOS device is configured to use iCloud backup for the DEVICE.
2. It would be nicer if I could know when was the latest successful backup
3. Open settings app on the iCloud backup configuration page

Doing that without any private API off course.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is **no public API** for determining wether iCloud backup is enabled for a device or not.

Comment: And any private?

Comment: @Idan I haven't checked any headers yet but there certainly has to be a private API for that.

Comment: @Idan There you go: https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/search?p=7&q=backup&type=&utf8=✓